# traverse nested list with single for

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, nested

I have a bunch of lists in lists. The nesting depth is determined at run-time and I only want to access them to a specific (run-time decided) depth to manipulate what ever is at that level in an arbitrary way.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this as simply as:

```
for x in access_list(nested_list, d)
    # do stuff at nesting-depth d
```

What `access_list` should do:

```
>>> mylist = [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 5], [6, 7]]]
>>> for d in range(4):
...     for l in access_list(mylist, d):
...         print((d, l))
(0, [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 5], [6, 7]]])
(1, [[[0, 1], [2, 3]])
(1, [[4, 5], [6, 7]]])
(2, [0, 1])
(2, [2, 3])
(2, [4, 5])
(2, [6, 7])
(3, 0)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
(3, 6)
(3, 7)
```

My attempt turned out to do essentially nothing:

```
def access_list(lists, d):
    if not d:
        return lists
    return [access_list(_list, d-1) for _list in lists]
```

It just returns the whole list structure again.
What could I do to make this work?

Comment: Too much text. Most people will not read this to answer. Please make your question more concise.

Comment: I agree with @pyNoob - make a minimal example. Input and expected output. The title of the question is to simple, why does it need so much text to get the idea across?

Comment: I agree with @pyNoob. You do indeed need recursion, so just make your question focus on the code that doesn't work and show some input and output.

Comment: edited the question now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This generator function should work for nested lists and saves memory as it doesn't build a list itself, but lazily produces the items:

```
def access_list(nested_list):
    if not isinstance(nested_list, list):
    # if not isinstance(nested_list, (list, set)): you get the idea
        yield nested_list
    else:
        for item in nested_list:
            for x in access_list(item):
                yield x
            # in Python 3, you can replace that loop by:
            # yield from access_list(item)
    return

> l = [1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6]]
> list(access_list(l))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you want access to nesting depth, the following will produce pairs `(item, depth)`:

```
def access_list(nested_list, d=0):
    if not isinstance(nested_list, list):
        yield nested_list, d
    else:
        for item in nested_list:
            for x in access_list(item, d=d+1):
                yield x
    return

> l = [1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6]]
> list(access_list(l))
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 2)]
```

Comment: Consider that a list could contain itself, in that case you'd need a set to keep track of seen lists.

Comment: Can you put non-hashable lists in a set?

Comment: Not directly, you could just put their `id` in a set, or cast to `tuple`.

Comment: In my case, lists will not contain themselves so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Then this answer should work fine. You can lose one nesting level in the for-loops with `itertools.product`, if you want to.

Comment: @timgeb I would have seen how `itertools.chain` helps in the `else` block, but for `product` I am not so sure...

Comment: Ok so all this does is completely flatten out my list down to the last element that is still a list, right? That's almost what I want, but rather than your version 2, giving me a flat list of pairs, I want, from depth `d+1` onwards, to directly return the data as is. It should not be flattened further. I do like the laziness though. Hold on, since there seems to be confusion in general as to what I really want, I'll try to be more specific in my question.

Comment: @kram1032 you can just change to the following: 'if not isinstance(nested_list, list) or d >= 2: yield nested_list'

Answer (score 4):

Pretty close!  Try subdividing the lists into progressively smaller chunks.

```
def access_list(x, d):
    if d and isinstance(x, list) and x:
       return access_list(x[0], d-1) + access_list(x[1:], d-1)
    return [x]
```

Okay, was hoping to avoid this cause it's a bit more complicated but this gives the exact output you're hoping for:

```
def access_list(x, d):
    def _access_list(x, d):
        if d and isinstance(x, types.ListType) and x:
            return access_list(x[0], d-1) + access_list(x[1:], d)
        return [x]
    return filter(lambda x: x, _access_list(x, d))
```

Comment: your method seems to do weird things starting from `d=2`

Comment: Recursion is weird, I agree :/

Comment: So, don't forget that in your example, your are printing out loop iteration, not nested depth.  They're not the same thing.  You have to pick if you want the function to correspond with the loop iteration or the recursion depth, otherwise you need to write to separate functions :)

Comment: fair enough :) - basically I want `d` to be the number of levels to flatten away, so `d=0` shouldn't change anything, `d=1` should flatten the top level, etc., just like what happens in my output.

Comment: yeah, after I got done whining I added the second function.  I feel like it's cheating a bit but it gets the job done :)

Comment: Yeah I saw, thanks, but I like the selected Answer better, in conjunction with a comment which turns it into what I wanted ☺

Answer (score 2):

Consider this solution:

```
def access_list(lists, d):
    if not d:
        return lists
    else:
        return sum(access_list(lists, d-1), [])
```

For example using this list: `l=[[[1,2],[3]],[[4],[5,[6,7]]]]`:

```
>>> access_list(l, 0)
[[1, 2], [3]]
[[4], [5, [6, 7]]]

>>> access_list(l, 1)
[1, 2]
[3]
[4]
[5, [6, 7]]

>>> access_list(l, 1)
1
2
3
4
5
[6, 7]
```

Comment: Flattening with `sum` is fun when you see it for the first time, but it's O(n^2).

Comment: Interesting, though I do not actually want/need it to be flattened out like that and if this indeed is O(n²) I'd rather use a different method. It does look like a nice simple solution though.

Answer (score 2):

you could use numpy arrays, it may work

```
import numpy
def access_list(lists, d):
    _lists=numpy.array(lists)
    if not d:
        L=[]
        for index in range(len(_lists)):
            L.append(_lists[index])
        return L
    return _lists[:]
```